# “Standard” approach to syncing data?

Tags: algorithms, synchronization

I'm wondering if there are any universally accepted "best" algorithms for syncing data sets.

I imagine there would be different solutions depending on circumstances:

- Are all peers online all the time or not?
- Are we more limited by bandwidth or processing power?
- Are data items large or small?
- Does data get modified and deleted or are we just accumulating a growing collection of data?

My question is what are the equivalents to *Djikstra's and Kruskal's algorthim* of my problem?

You might say the two well known algorithms mentioned solve problems which are much more specific. That's probably true, so let me narrow down my question:

What is a good way to calculate a diff between two versions of a large growing set of very small chunks of data? Assume data is never deleted or modified, synchronisation happens between a limited number of peers, somewhat regularly but there is no real *server and client* situation, any peer could have some new data.

I feel I just don't know where to start looking, what papers to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that there is any "standard" or "best" approach, as the technique that is appropriate will depend on the setting.  However, I recommend you start by looking at the algorithms used by [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) and the [Remote Differential Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Differential_Compression) scheme.  More generally, look at techniques for [delta compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding).

Comment: Yes! I don't know why I didn't think of rsync, but it certainly is a start.